# Let $(G,∗,I)$ be a group and let $g \in G$ satisfy $g^{n} = I$ for some odd number n. Prove that there is an $h \in G$ such that $g = h^{2}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This was an exam question I was unable to answer. I've been thinking about it for hours now and am still unable to figure out how to approach this problem. Any help will be much appreciated :).

It's been made clear to me that I should note my own efforts so here it is:

We have that $g \in G$ and $g^{n} = I$ where $n$ is an odd number. If there exists a $g = h^{2}$ then $h^{2n} = I$. And this is as far as I got.

Comment: Set $h:=g^{\frac{n+1}2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It's particularly important that you show your own work and efforts on the problem, otherwise it will be probably downvoted and eventually closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $n$ is odd, $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is well defined. Just take $h:=g^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$. So $h^2=g^{n+1}=g^ng=g$, since $g^n=1$

Comment: 1) $n+1$ is even, but not necessarily ${n+1\over 2}$, 2) $g^n=1$ doesn't mean it has *order* $n$ – it could be a divisor of $n$.

Comment: You are right, edited it

Comment: A small nitpick: Technically, the first sentence should read: "Since $n$ is odd, $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is a nonnegative integer and so $g^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ is well-defined." [Note that $i=\frac{n+1}{2}$ is well-defined for any integer $n$, what we need is for $g^i$ to be well-defined...] But overall your answer is clear.